# Can't retrive feature using draw interaction : featureRetriver[0] is undefined

Tags: openlayers, web-mapping

I have a problem retrieving geometry created using draw interaction.

Context :
I want to make a WFS intersection from a point drawn by a user. The user has to click on a button to create geometry and then getting the geometry

For this I have created :

1. A `draw` interaction triggered by a click on a button `id=select`
2. A function `GeneratePOSTRequest()` to send the created geometry to the server and execute intersection

When I run my current script I'm getting the following error "featureRetriver[0] is undefined".

I have searched on google but I can't find any information to solve the problem.

```js
let draw;
//Draw function
document.getElementById('select').addEventListener('click', function () {
    drawSource.clear();
    draw = new Draw({
        source: drawSource,
        type: 'Point',
    });
    map.addInteraction(draw);
    draw.on("drawend", (e) => {
        draw.setActive(false);
        var drawingStatus = draw.getActive();
        if (drawingStatus === false) {
            GeneratePOSTRequest();
        };
    });
});

function GeneratePOSTRequest() {
    var featureRetriver = drawShape.getSource().getFeatures();
    var SelectorPoly = featureRetriver[0].getGeometry()
    var featureRequest = new WFS().writeGetFeature({
        srsName: 'EPSG:3857',
        featurePrefix: 'qgs',
        featureTypes: ['paris_geom'],
        outputFormat: 'gml3',
        filter: intersectsFilter('paris_geom', SelectorPoly, 'EPSG:3857')
    });
    console.log(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(featureRequest));
    // then post the request and add the received features to a layer
    fetch('http://192.168.1.12/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(featureRequest)
    }).then(function(response) {
        return response.text();
    }).then(function(text) {
        var features = new WFS().readFeatures(text);
        SelectedGeomSource.addFeatures(features);
        drawSource.clear();
    });
};
```

If i use 2 buttons (1 to create geometry and 1 to send the request) then it works fine...
Exemple :

```js
document.getElementById('select').addEventListener('click', function () {
    drawSource.clear();
    draw = new Draw({
        source: drawSource,
        type: 'Point',
    });
    map.addInteraction(draw);
});

document.getElementById('send').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var featureRetriver = drawShape.getSource().getFeatures();
    var SelectorPoly = featureRetriver[0].getGeometry()
    var featureRequest = new WFS().writeGetFeature({
        srsName: 'EPSG:3857',
        featurePrefix: 'qgs',
        featureTypes: ['angkor_polygon'],
        outputFormat: 'gml3',
        filter: intersectsFilter('angkor_polygon', SelectorPoly, 'EPSG:3857')
    });
    console.log(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(featureRequest));
    // then post the request and add the received features to a layer
    fetch('http://192.168.1.12/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(featureRequest)
    }).then(function(response) {
        return response.text();
    }).then(function(text) {
        var features = new WFS().readFeatures(text);
        SelectedGeomSource.addFeatures(features);
        drawSource.clear();
    });
});
```

Do you have any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: The `drawend` event fires before the completed drawing is added to the source.  Either pass `e.feature` to your `GeneratePOSTRequest` function or set an `addfeature` event listener on `drawShape.getSource()` and call `GeneratePOSTRequest` in that.

Comment: Thanks Mike! I used addfeature in a different position than you suggested and it works fine. See my next post to see the working script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following mike's anwser, I modified the script. Here is a working example :

```js
let draw;
//Draw function
document.getElementById('select').addEventListener('click', function () {
    CartoVectorTiles.setOpacity(1)
    SelectedGeomSource.clear();
    draw = new Draw({
        source: drawSource,
        type: 'Point',
    });
    map.addInteraction(draw);
    draw.on("drawend", (e) => {
        draw.setActive(false);
        SelectedGeomSource.clear();
    });
});

//Send post request after the completed drawing is added to the source
drawSource.on("addfeature", function() {
    GeneratePOSTRequest();
});

//Send request to the server
function GeneratePOSTRequest() {
    var featureRetriver = drawShape.getSource().getFeatures();
    var SelectorPoly = featureRetriver[0].getGeometry()
    var featureRequest = new WFS().writeGetFeature({
        srsName: 'EPSG:3857',
        featurePrefix: 'qgs',
        featureTypes: ['paris_geom'],
        outputFormat: 'gml3',
        filter: intersectsFilter('paris_geom', SelectorPoly, 'EPSG:3857')
    });
    console.log(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(featureRequest));
    // then post the request and add the received features to a layer
    fetch('http://192.168.1.12/cgi-bin/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(featureRequest)
    }).then(function(response) {
        return response.text();
    }).then(function(text) {
        var features = new WFS().readFeatures(text);
        SelectedGeomSource.addFeatures(features);
        CartoVectorTiles.on("change", CartoVectorTiles.setOpacity(0.5));
        drawSource.clear();
    });
};
```